# Skip first n items of GroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, numpy-slicing

I've grouped my dataframe by the content's IDs with
`df_grouped = df_input.groupby("ID")`

Now, I would like to skip/delete the first *n* groups ("rows") of the GroupBy object (*df_grouped*), so that the "new" GroupBy object starts at n+1.
Here is some illustration:

```
| ID | Content |
| ---| --------|
| 3  | just    |
| 4  | a       |
| 6  | short   |
| 10 | sample  |
```

Skip the first 2 (*n=2*) groups of df_gouped with something like `df_grouped[2:]`

```
| ID | Content |
| ---| --------|
| 6  | short   |
| 10 | sample  |
```

After skipping the first n groups, the data should still be stored as a GroupBy object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter first, then group

```
df.loc[df.ID.isin(df.ID.unique().tolist()[2:])].groupby("ID")
```